# Strange java concurrency behavior

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following code:

```
class Hi
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      int a = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
          a = a + i;
          System.out.println ("a before sleep is " + a);
          try {
              Thread.sleep(4000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {

          }
          System.out.println ("a after sleep is " + a);
      }
   }
}
```

I open two console windows and do `java Hi` in first one. Then wait for about 10 seconds seconds and do the same in the second window. Both outputs are the same:

```
a before sleep is 1
a after sleep is 1
a before sleep is 2
a after sleep is 2
a before sleep is 4
a after sleep is 4
a before sleep is 7
a after sleep is 7
a before sleep is 11
a after sleep is 11
```

with no interleaving. So what's the stir about concurrency issues if I even didn't bother to use `synchronized` statement? Is it because the code run from different console windows is executed on different processor cores? If so, I've carried out this experiment about 20 times and the results are still the same.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: So you're running 2 different programs?

Comment: Note that even if you did have multiple threads, *local variables* still aren't normally shared.  If you start two threads, and both threads call a `mainProcess` method, and that method has a local variable (like `a` in your example), each method would still have its own copy of that variable and there wouldn't be a concurrency issue.

Comment: @ajb: Although if two variables refer to the same *object*, you again have sharing. (Not relevant for primitives like the `int` here though.)

Comment: The two are in different JVMS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I open two console windows and do java Hi in first one. Then wait for about 10 seconds seconds and do the same in the second window.

You're starting two entirely separate process. That's not using multithreading at all - each process will have its own variables, its own output, everything.

To see multithreading, you need to create threads in a *single* process. For example:

```
import java.util.Random;

class Counter implements Runnable {
    private int a;

    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            a++;
            System.out.println(name + " Before sleep, a = " + a);
            try {
                // Add a little more uncertainty...
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignored
            }
            System.out.println(name + " After sleep, a = " + a);
        }
    }
}

public class ThreadingTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(counter);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(counter);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: started to notice you are everywhere :P

Comment: @Zapadlo And please note that Jon's example will show interleaving only because `a` is an instance field in a common object, not a local variable inside `run`.

Answer (score 4):

You have two different JVM's so two main threads running on two different JVM's so concurrency dont apply.

Yes if you have two threads within same JVM then concurrency applies.

Answer (score 3):

These are two separate processes on your computer. They do not share data or anything else. They are no more related then, for example, your web browser and your wordprocessor. They each have their own separate "a" variable, each completely unrelated to the other.

Concurrency issues arise when multiple threads in the same process space try to access the same variable. That does not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

As here you are running two different processes, no matter how many times you run this code you will get same result. As both of these programs will be running within two separate processes.

To run these programs in multi threaded way you have to implement two threads and start them.